# clearInterval does not clear setInterval inside function

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, clearinterval

How do I clear interval for the setInterval inside the StartGame function ?(present one is not working)

```js
document.getElementById("rndletter").addEventListener("click", function StartGame() ** {
  setInterval(function() ** {
    var result0 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
    var result1 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
    var result2 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
  }, 2000);
});
document.getElementById("stprndletter").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval();
});
```

```html
<button id="rndletter">Start game</button>
<button id="stprndletter">Stop game</button>
<td style="text-align: center; color: blue; font-size: 150%;">
  <b>
        <div id="result0"><br />
        </div>
    </b></td>
<td style="text-align: center; color: brown; font-size: 150%;">
  <b>
        <div id="result1"><br /></div>
    </b></td>
<td style="text-align: center; color: hotpink; font-size: 150%;"><b>
        <div id="result2"><br /></div>
    </b></td>
```

Comment: setInterval returns an ID, and you can use that Id and pass it to clearInterval

Comment: Look at your current code. Think about how you're currently expecting it to work. Now think what would happen if you set *two* `setInterval`s, and wanted to clear one of them. How would that *possibly* work with your current expectations? Then go [read some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and see how it actually works.

Comment: Ohhhh ok Got it so I need to set an ID for the setInterval so that clearInterval can refer to that and stop, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after reading the docs, for anyone who searches the same, I have done this: (added an ID `nIntervID`)

```
let nIntervId;

document.getElementById("rndletter").addEventListener("click", function {
    nIntervId = setInterval(function() {
        var result0 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);
        var result1 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);     
        var result2 = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (122 - 97)) + 97);

        document.getElementById("result0").innerText = result0;
        document.getElementById("result1").innerText = result1;
        document.getElementById("result2").innerText = result2;
    },2000);});
    document.getElementById("stprndletter").addEventListener("click", function() {
        clearInterval(nIntervId);
        // release our intervalID from the variable
        nIntervId = null; 
    });
});
```